# How to remove https://optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com call execution when the developed application runs?

Tags: angular, typescript, security, google-api, owasp

I have run the OWASP ZAP tool to identify the vulnerability issues in my developed application using **angular 10** and **spring-boot**. There I got ***Missing Anti-clickjacking Header*** vulnerability for the below URL.

***https://optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com/downloads?name=236676787&target=OPTIMIZATION_TARGET_LANGUAGE_DETECTION***

I need to know how to fix this issue by stopping this call or by any other method.

Answer (score 7):

Same kind of behaviour on my side. I have found this talking about the subject:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/157884177/chrome-appearing-to-download-without-me-downloading-anything?hl=en

You can see chrome background downloads using: chrome://download-internals/

It seems there are options to prevent from downloading those files: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1311753#c24
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/optimization_guide/core/optimization_guide_features.cc;l=85

`add parameter "--disable-features=OptimizationGuideModelDownloading,OptimizationHintsFetching,OptimizationTargetPrediction,OptimizationHints"`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can ignoring the alert, because it's a chrome-browser event https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/dUop7AuPFJQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).